# Haskell void function

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

I'm new to Haskell. In the Monad docs, there is an example use for the void function:

```
>>> void (Left 8675309)
Left 8675309
>>> void (Right 8675309)
Right ()
```

I'm having a tough time figuring out why this is the case.

I see that void is defined as: `void x = () <$ x` and `(<$) = fmap . const` but I cannot figure out why there is a difference between Left and Right.

Any hints?

Comment: Because `fmap` maps the value defined in the `Right`, not in the `Left`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `fmap` maps the value defined in the `Right`, not in the `Left`. Indeed, `Either` is defined as:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

and the `Functor` of `Either a` is thus implemented as:

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
    fmap _ (Left x) = Left x
    fmap f (Right x) = Right (f x)
```

This makes sense, since the `Functor` expects a type of kind `* -> *`, and thus the `fmap :: Functor f => (b -> c) -> f b -> f c` makes a mapping for `Either` with `fmap :: (b -> c) -> Either a b -> Either a c`.

Since `void` is defined as `void = fmap (const ())`, this thus means that if we make an analysis per case, we see:

```
fmap (const ()) (Left x) = Left x
fmap (const ()) (Right x) = Right (const () x) = Right ()
```